# error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

hi i am getting this error though i tried to change the new to i am stil getting this problem can anyone tell me what should i do. I have completely changed the page also database but still same error.

error>

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''calendar_admin' WHERE teacher_id='ipcst123' and password='a141c47927929bc2d1fb6' 
>         at line 1

my code >

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['teacherId'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password=md5($password);
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }


$query ="SELECT * FROM 'calendar_admin' WHERE teacher_id="."'".$username."' and password="."'".$password."' ";
 $resultat = $bdd->query($query) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
 $res = $resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


foreach($res as $result){
$pass=md5($password);
$user=$result["teacher_id"];

if ($pass==$result["password"]&& $username == $user ){
echo "login Success";
session_start();
$_SESSION['teacher_id'] = $username;
header('Location:/addEvents.php');
}else{

    header('Location:/login.php');
    //echo "Incorrect Password";
}
}
```

Comment: `FROM 'calendar_admin'` Wrong quotes!

Comment: Lordie lordie lordie.

Comment: Thats not your actual password in bold there is it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know what you mean :) [no no no](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd807T4eP5M)

Comment: `$query ="SELECT * FROM calendar_admin WHERE teacher_id='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";`

Comment: `md5()` is not what you should use for encrypting passwords. Use `password_hash()` instead.

Comment: @HardyMathew close, but no cigar.

Comment: @Fred-ii- True Friend...!!! :(

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Yeah Sam*, MD5 is so old, even DustBuster won't come near it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- every time i though cnai have to post this as comment or answer and missed my cake!!

Comment: @HardyMathew You should have hit when the iron was hot! *MMmmm, cake....*

Answer (score 1):

You should use backticks instead of single quotes :

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM `calendar_admin` WHERE teacher_id='".$username."' and `password`='".$password."' ";
```

or just remove them

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM calendar_admin WHERE teacher_id='".$username."' and `password`='".$password."' ";
```

And since you use PDO, you should bind parameters, but not concatenate them into the query:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM calendar_admin WHERE teacher_id= :teacher and `password`= :password ";

$sth = $bdd->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam(':teacher',$username);
$sth->bindParam(':password',$password);
$sth->execute();
$res = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Around column and table names has to be backticks, not single quotes. O rnothing if the names aren't from reserved words (*or spaces, or hyphens, or anything else that MySQL will scream about*, @Fred -ii- in comments below):

```
`calendar_admin`
```

The full query:

```
$query ="SELECT * 
         FROM `calendar_admin` 
         WHERE teacher_id = '" . $username . "' AND                    
               password = '" . $password . "'";
```

Don't forget to escape data from user inputs.

Comment: *"Or nothing if the names aren't from reserved words:* - or spaces, or hyphens, or anything else that MySQL will scream about ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: you're right, I put there the variant which is using. I've never seen column name with a space, is it allowed?

Comment: There is a lot more to *improve* in OP's code!

Comment: Yes they're allowed but require ticks around it. Not good practice, but allowed.

Comment: Using hyphens for example `my-table` MySQL translates that to "my **minus** table" thinking one wants to do "math" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I know it means _minus_, but didn't know if I can use it in the table/column name :-)

Comment: Oh sure you can. For both tables and columns, but it's discouraged since they do tend to pose problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM calendar_admin 
 WHERE teacher_id = '$username'
   AND password = '$password';
";
```

Next, take a look at prepared statements

Comment: thank you everyone ...i got my mistake ..what a silly one was it ....:P