# How to fix You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, sql

I'm working now with SQL to sum all values, I used this query

```
$Withdraw = query("SELECT carid SUM(amount)
                   FROM tbl_fuel 
                   GROUP BY carid");
render("./report/expensespervehicle.php", ["title" => "Withdrawal", "Withdraw" => $Withdraw]);
```

but when i ran it, I got an error and says

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(amount) FROM tbl_fuel GROUP BY carid'

please help me, this is the first time i used that query

Comment: You need to use a comma after carid in the select query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in your SQL syntax;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923598/error-in-your-sql-syntax)

Comment: 'Select carid, sum(amount) from tbl_fuel group by carid'

Comment: thank you for all your replies sir.

Answer (score 2):

Your obvious problem is the missing comma.  But you should also provide a name for the second column:

```
SELECT carid, SUM(amount) as total_amount
FROM tbl_fuel 
GROUP BY carid;
```

Comment: @N-Jay If this resolves your question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thank you sir, but its only displayed the carid, the total amount doesn't display, and it says "Undefined index: amount"

Comment: @N-Jay The index is `total_amount` with this approach. If you want it to be `amount` change the alias from `total_amount` to `amount`. e.g. `SUM(amount) as amount`

Answer (score 0):

**Use comma after every column and also use alias for SUM(amount) for better practice,**

```
SELECT carid, SUM(amount) FROM tbl_fuel GROUP BY carid
```

Answer (score 0):

finally! this code work properly, i just have added this line to my codes to display carid, reg_num(registration number from other table named tbl_vehicle) and amount(from table named tbl_fuel)

```
$Withdraw = query("SELECT tbl_fuel.carid,
tbl_vehicle.reg_num,
sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', '')) + 0.0) as amount
FROM tbl_fuel 
LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle 
on tbl_fuel.carid=tbl_vehicle.carid
GROUP BY carid");
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you are trying to select 2 columns:

- carid
- sum(amount)

so it means you should use `,` between these columns.

```
$Withdraw = query("SELECT carid, SUM(amount)
                   FROM tbl_fuel 
                   GROUP BY carid");
```

Comment: Ok no problem. :)